# GET http://localhost:3000/api/eventNames net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, quasar

I am trying to get axios working with my vue project so I can test the backend of my app. It seems that I am having issues setting up the axios server as I'm getting a connection refused on the baseURL that I have setup. I posted my api.js file that I created under service/api.js. Any information on things to look at to get this resolved would be greatly appreciated.

**/src/service/api.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default () => {
    const instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
        withCredentials: false,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/jason"
        }
    });
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Is your http server running? If yes, then try adding CORS headers.

Comment: Yes I ran npm run serve on my project and going through local host http://localhost:8081/ to where I see the error. For CORS is this all I need to add in the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'?

Comment: If possible can you please elaborate with proper screenshot of error from backend part?